# I just got $100 back Vs. I just got back 100$

Tags: idiomatic-language

I bought something online, and I cancelled. I got a refund.

What's more idiomatic?

> I just **got** $100 **back**.

Or

> I just **got back** $100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are possible, but I feel that, especially in speech, "I got $100 back" is more likely.  "Get back" is a separable phrasal-verb. Moreover expressions like "get my wallet back" are certainly possible.